# Why is there different Geometric Least Square Means for same treatment?

Tags: statistical-significance, anova, inference, mean, sas

According to the study protocol, we used the MIXED model technique (in SAS) to estimate the ratio for example C vs A ,  C vs D, and its 90% confidence interval. However, in the ANOVA output, for treatment C, different geometric least square means values are showing (i.e, different value of geo lsm for C in C vs A with respect to C vs D). The number of subjects, dimensions, all are identical then why is this happening? what should I check?